# IE11 embedded font won't work - tried all the usual approaches

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I have a set of embedded fonts that work fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari - but, surprise, surprise, not in IE (v11, but tried in 10 and that didn't work either).

I can get some to load in IE, but not others. Sample of css:

```
/* working */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FoundersGroteskWeb-Semibold';
    src: url(./fonts/FoundersGroteskWeb-Semibold.eot);
    src: url(./fonts/FoundersGroteskWeb-Semibold.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(./fonts/FoundersGroteskWeb-Semibold.woff) format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
            }

/* not working */    
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FoundersGroteskX-CondensedWeb-Bold';
    src: url(./fonts/FoundersGroteskX-CondensedWeb-Bold.eot);
    src: url(./fonts/FoundersGroteskX-CondensedWeb-Bold.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(./fonts/FoundersGroteskX-CondensedWeb-Bold.woff) format('woff');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The fonts are served, all named correctly, etc. One difference I noticed is that all the other browsers were loading the woff file, whereas IE was using the (first, non #iefix) eot file. So I tried deleting all references to the eot files, forcing IE11 to use the woff. Again, it loaded the first one fine, but didn't use the second one (all other browsers loaded both with no problem).

When I check in the network tab on IE, I can see the 200 response for the first font, but there's nothing at all for the second font, looking like it might be choking on the parse of the css. However, given that the two declarations are identical apart from the font name, I can't see why that might be.

Anyone got any ideas what else I can try, because I've run out of straws to clutch at?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE 9 (and I think 10 and 11 as well) have 31 character limit on font face name declaration. Please try and rename your font name to "FoundersGroteskX-CndWeb-Bld"; which is 30 characters, just to be safe (because this limitation of 31 characters is including quotes and semi-colon.

Comment: That did it - thank you so much, I was going out of my mind!

Comment: Long live IE and it's quirks. You will be surprised to see that this limitation was not there in IE7/IE8 :D

Comment: The Windows API has always had a font name length of max 30 characters. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ek64h34.aspx for instance. What I find odd is that longer names appeared to work in IE7 and 8! Wait, what if this was a bug in IE7 and 8 and it involved buffer overrun, and the bug was finally fixed in IE9.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on that then its been a while but it is possible that IE7 and 8 did not follow MS specification

Answer (score 0):

as per your earlier suggestion I also tried to minimize font names but this still does not work in latest IE:

```
</style>
<style type="text/css">

@font-face { 
  font-family:"Avenir"; 
  src: url("./Fonts/Avenir.eot");
  src: url("./Fonts/Avenir.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),  
       url("./Fonts/Avenir.woff") format("woff"); 
} 

</style>
```

Do you think IE no longer accepts woff fonts?

Comment: I don't think that woff format is the problem. Do the fonts load in other browsers? Which version of IE are you using? Do other woff fonts load in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Check font download security, it should be enable to load font icon.

Navigate to:

> IE>Internet options>Intranet>Custom Level>Downloads>Font Download